# DOMContentLoaded not loading

Tags: javascript

The bottom code is trying to call a function once domcontent has been loaded. However it doesn't seem to be firing. The function outputs to the divs in the dynamically generated table. 
What i'm trying to do is load countdown(...) to place a countdown timer for each item loaded onto the table. I have used this addeventlistener because I read that I needed my DOM to be loaded before I could utilize the div tags.

This table loads an xml document.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var table;
    var i;
    var xmlhttp = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "auction.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    table = ("<table>");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += ("<tr><td>Item Name : ");
        table += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("ItemName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        iname = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("ItemName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        table += ("</td></tr>");
        table += ("<tr><td>Start Price : ");
        table += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("StartPrice")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        table += ("</td></tr>");
        table += ("<tr><td>Category : ");
        table += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Category")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        table += ("</td></tr>");
        table += ("<tr><td>Current Bid : ");
        table += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("BidPrice")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        icurrent = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("BidPrice")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        table += ("</td></tr>");
        table += ("<tr><td>Buy It Now Price : ");
        table += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("NowPrice")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        inow = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("NowPrice")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        table += ("</td></tr>");
        table += ("<tr><td>Highest Bidder : ");
        table += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("HighestBidder")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        table += ("</td></tr>");
        var yr = 2018;
        var m = 5;
        var d = 10;
        var hr = 12;
        var min = 12;
        table += ("<tr>");;
        table += ("<td> Time Left : </td>");
        table += ("<td><div id=\"dday\"></div></td>");
        table += ("<td><div id=\"dhour\"></div></td>");
        table += ("<td><div id=\"dmin\"></div></td>");
        table += ("<td><div id=\"dsec\"></div></td>");
        table += ("</tr>");
        table += ("<script>");
        table += ("xmlDoc.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\",    countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min),false");
        table += ("</script>");
    }
}
table += ("</table>");
document.getElementById('listinglist').innerHTML = table;
//countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min);
}

function countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min) {
theyear=yr;themonth=m;theday=d;thehour=hr;theminute=min;
var today=new Date();
var todayy=today.getYear();
if (todayy < 1000) {todayy+=1900;}
var todaym=today.getMonth();
var todayd=today.getDate();
var todayh=today.getHours();
var todaymin=today.getMinutes();
var todaysec=today.getSeconds();
var todaystring1=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec;
var todaystring=Date.parse(todaystring1)+(tz*1000*60*60);
var futurestring1=(montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+hr+":"+min);
var futurestring=Date.parse(futurestring1)-(today.getTimezoneOffset()*(1000*60));
var dd=futurestring-todaystring;
var dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
var dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
var dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
var dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
    document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML = "HH";
    document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML = dhour;
    document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML = dmin;
    document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML = dsec;
    setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)", 1000);

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing relevant code.  What is `xmlDoc`?  What is `table`.  Where is the content you're creating inserted into the page.  What happening are you trying to listen to (loading of some XML document)?  Why are you passing a string to `setTimeout()` as that is nearly always a no-no and prevents access to local variables.  Why are you passing `countdown(...)` to addEventListener.  That calls it immediately and passes the return value to addEventListener.

Comment: There are a lot of different things wrong with this code.  If you back up and fully describe what you're trying to accomplish form the start, we might be able to help.  Please describe the problem, not your attempt at a solution.  If you want to understand why, then read about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Please use the edit link to add the description of what you're trying to do to your question (so it's not just in the comments).  Also, I don't see any code that actually adds the `table` stuff to your web page.  I think you're misunderstanding when you would use DOMContentLoaded which means this is an XY problem.  You're asking about a flawed solution, so we need to understand the whole problem so we can help you come up with a correct and likely different solution.

Comment: you should use async.

Comment: What do you mean by async? I'm quite new to javascript and I've been picking things up as I go so I am not familiar with many of the functions. Sorry

Comment: It looks like you're missing the end of your `loadXmlDoc()` function definition (at least no closing brace) and there's still no code that actually does anything with the `table` variable.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see what you mean. Sorry, added the code in.

Answer (score 0):

The DOMContentLoaded event is to notify you when the original HTML page has been loaded and the DOM that was present in the downloaded HTML of the page is now available and ready to use.

Your countdown timers do not need to use DOMContentLoaded at all because you know exactly when your content is present (when you insert it yourself).

I don't quite understand exactly what you're trying to do with the countdown timers, but I would think you could have a single timer (that you don't need to insert with a `<script>` tag - you can just start your own timer right after you insert the content) that would update all your countdowns.

FYI, there are all sorts of problems with your code:

1. You seem to be trying to use the `table` variable to add your generated content to the page, but you're doing so outside of the `loadXMLDoc()` function where the `table` variable exists.  I presume you should be doing this inside the function.
2. You don't seem to be actually calling `loadXMLDoc()` anywhere.
3. You may need to use DOMContentLoaded before your call `loadXMLDoc()`, but you don't need to use it for your `countdown()` function.
4. There's no need to insert script tags here.  You can just directly execute whatever code you want after you insert the table.
5. You're using synchronous Ajax which is a bad user experience in the browser.  you should be using asynchronous Ajax which will require some different code to process the response.
6. I can't imagine you actually need to support IE5 and IE6 (or even IE7 or IE8 for that matter) so you can remove that part of the Ajax code.
7. Your countdown function appears to be trying to use variable names that don't exist.
8. You are using multiple elements with the same ID values.  You cannot do that.  An id must be unique in an HTML document.

Comment: Each product from the xml in the table should have its own countdown timer. This means that there will be multiple countdown timers on the page. I have tried inserting the countdown timer without the DOMContentLoaded in there but chromes debugger said that countdown is returning to an id that is non existant. That led me to believe that the table needs to finish loading before i can access the id tags.

Comment: 1) loadXMLDoc is called in the htm file in an onload.
2) document.getElementById('listinglist').innerHTML = table; I'm assuming this is what you mean when you say output. This goes back to the htm file. 
3) table seems to be in the loadxmldoc function?

Comment: @JianYA - You may need to wait for the DOM to be loaded before you call `loadXMLDoc()`, but once it has run (which will insert its content), the countdown timers don't need to wait for anything more.  I'm sorry, but there are just so many things wrong with this code (see the partial list I added to my question) that we can't possibly fix them all for you.

Comment: I will attempt to fix the rest of the issues but for now if I called the countdown timer function in the table, it won't see the div tag. loadXMLDoc is supposed to load the DOM.

Comment: @JianYA - OK, I'll see about taking a stab at fixing a bunch of things for you.  That will take a bit of time.  I will post a comment back when I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to see what I can do with my current code as well.

Comment: @JianYA - I can't figure out what the `countdown()` function is supposed to do.  It refers to variables that are not defined anywhere in the code you posted so thus I can't fix that for you.

Comment: @JianYA - also, you're using multiple elements with the same id value which is not legal in HTML.  Id values must be unique in the document.

Comment: I have updated to show the countdown function. The table with the same id was suggested in another post